# Can I specify a username and password to access a file over HTTP?

Tags: html, apache, http

I have several files in a directory on an Apache server that are accessible through an ordinary URL and can be downloaded publicly.  I know I can protect this folder through Apache htaccess files but I want to automate the process of sending the username and password when a user clicks a link.

I am aware there are basic HTTP authentication methods that can be used to transmit a username and password, but I have heard these are not very security conscious so I wondered if there were any other methods you could recommend?

Any usernames or passwords transmitted over clicked links will be via HTTPS.

Comment: You have to ask yourself why you would want to protect them with a password if they are publicly available.

You certainly have another idea behind this, could you explain it?

Comment: [Digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) is alright. If it's all done via HTTPS, even Basic Auth is ok, security-wise.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a server-side language, and store the information/control access that way.  You don't need to use .htaccess with that direction.

Security speaking, it's the best method, in my opinion, because you validate everything on the back end.

**Updated code:**

```
<?php

# Wrap this in your credentials -- #

$directory_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/directory/path/here/";
$file_path = $directory_path . $_GET['downloadfile'];

if ($file_exists = fopen ($file_path, "r")) 
{
    $file_size = filesize($file_path);
    $file_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
    $file_extenion = strtolower($file_parts["extension"]);

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$file_parts["basename"]."\"");
    header("Content-length: $file_size");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly

    while(!feof($file_exists)) 
    {
        $buffer = fread($file_exists, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($file_exists);
exit;

# -- End credential wrap -- #
?>
```

Then you could call the file with `download.php?downloadfile=something.jpg`

You'll have to put the appropriate headers/mime-types for your files and wrap that in your credential validatation, but that should work for ya.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I am using PHP on the server side of things.  The problem is that if someone knew the URL of a file they could simply type it into a browser and download that file e.g. www.mysite.com/filestosecure/myfile.pdf  This would bypass all the PHP anyway so basic authentication seems to be the only way to me but I would appreciate any alternatives.

Comment: You use a download-script to pase the files, say something like this:  /yourdirectory/download.php?filepath=something.jpg - and then you can build the file that way (if the credentials match up).  I can provide a better example, if you'd like

Comment: Yes I would be very appreciative if you could build a sample script.

Comment: You can store the files above your `www` directory, so that direct access is impossible.